docker buildx does not trigger cache invalidation

Using docker: v27
Using docker buildx plugin: v0.16

It seems that the build cache invalidation is not happening @ a layer where a specific build arg is used to determine an environment variable.
Considering the following Dockerfile example:
FROM someBaseImage:5.4.0 AS base

# Install dependencies stage
FROM base AS build

COPY --chown=hive:hive package.json package-lock.json .npmrc ./
RUN npm ci --production=false && rm -f .npmrc

COPY --chown=hive:hive src/ src/

ARG RELEASE=dev
ENV EVELIN_RELEASE=${RELEASE}

RUN npm run build

RUN if [ "${NODE_ENV}" = "production" ]; \
    then npm prune --production;  \
    fi

FROM base

COPY --from=build /app /app
COPY --chown=hive:hive .eslintignore .prettierrc.js tsconfig.json ./

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev:server"]


I would expect that the cache invalidation would happen already at:
ARG RELEASE=dev
ENV EVELIN_RELEASE=${RELEASE}

if on a subsequent docker build execution the RELEASE build arg changes. This is the whole build command:
docker buildx build --progress=plain -f /docker/Dockerfile --build-arg 'RELEASE=09705c14' . --cache-from app:latest --cache-to type=registry,ref=someRepo,mode=min,oci-mediatypes=true,image-manifest=true --push -t app:latest

but apparently the build arg is not considered as cache bust factor in this context. What is strange is that on CI the behaviour is as mentioned. But on the local machine it is behaving as expected, also according to the docs: https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#impact-on-build-caching
P.S. When trying to reproduce the error on my local machine (using docker virtualization) I am using the same builder-instance that I'm using in kubernetes.
For completeness-sake I can show the CI logs output:
$ docker buildx build ${DOCKER_DIND_BUILDX_ARGS[@]}
docker buildx build --progress=plain -f /docker/Dockerfile --build-arg 'RELEASE=09705c14' . --cache-from app:latest --cache-to type=registry,ref=someRepo,mode=min,oci-mediatypes=true,image-manifest=true --push -t app:latest
#0 building with "kube-new" instance using kubernetes driver
#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 778B done
#1 DONE 0.0s
#2 [auth] sharing credentials for someRegistry
#2 DONE 0.0s
#3 [internal] load metadata for someBaseImage:5.4.0
#3 DONE 0.1s
#4 [internal] load .dockerignore
#4 transferring context: 89B done
#4 DONE 0.0s
#5 [internal] load build context
#5 DONE 0.0s
#6 [base 1/1] FROM someBaseImage:5.4.0@sha256:...
#6 resolve someBaseImage:5.4.0@sha256:... 0.0s done
#6 DONE 0.0s
#7 importing cache manifest from app:latest
#7 inferred cache manifest type: application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json done
#7 DONE 0.3s
#5 [internal] load build context
#5 transferring context: 3.11MB 0.2s done
#5 DONE 0.2s
#8 [build 5/5] RUN if [ "${NODE_ENV}" = "production" ];     then npm prune --production;      fi
#8 CACHED
#9 [stage-2 1/2] COPY --from=build /app /app
#9 CACHED
#10 [build 1/5] COPY --chown=hive:hive package.json package-lock.json .npmrc ./
#10 CACHED
#11 [build 2/5] RUN npm ci --production=false && rm -f .npmrc
#11 CACHED
#12 [build 3/5] COPY --chown=hive:hive src/ src/
#12 CACHED
#13 [build 4/5] RUN npm run build
#13 CACHED
#14 [stage-2 2/2] COPY --chown=hive:hive .eslintignore .prettierrc.js tsconfig.json ./
#14 CACHED
#15 exporting to image
#15 exporting layers done
#15 exporting manifest sha256:... 0.0s done
#15 exporting config sha256:... done
#15 exporting attestation manifest sha256:... 0.0s done
#15 exporting manifest list sha256:... 0.0s done
#15 pushing layers
#15 pushing layers 0.3s done
#15 pushing manifest for app:latest@sha256:...
#15 pushing manifest for app:latest@sha256:... 0.3s done
#15 DONE 1.2s
#16 exporting cache to registry
#16 preparing build cache for export
...
#16 writing cache image manifest sha256:... 0.1s done
#16 DONE 0.5s


So guys I figured out the culprit. The issue on the way how I passed the build argument. Instead of passing it like this
--build-arg 'RELEASE=09705c14'

it should rather be passed like this
--build-arg RELEASE=09705c14


If a Bourne shell is processing the command line (anything called sh or zsh or bash or dash) then those two lines should be identical.
